# How to use a Gmail app password with smtp?

Tags: email, smtpmail

**Q:** how can I use a Gmail app password with smtp?

Google recently disabled the "less secure apps" option for Gmail,
so I went ahead and created an [app
password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en)
so I could continue to access my Gmail account from the comfort of
Emacs (`mu4e` + offlineimap).

offlineimap (and therefore `mu4e`) is able to access my account
when using the app password I generated, so that part is working.
However, I cannot *send* any messages.  Every time I try, I get an
error message that reads:

```
https://support.google.com/mail/?p=InvalidSecondFactor i20-20020a05620a249400b006a6ce613c7csm10357803qkn.89 - gsmtp in response to AUTH
```

(Yes, I have turned on 2-factor authentication as required to generate an app password.)

I have updated my smtp credentials with:

```
(setq smtpmail-auth-credentials
      '(("smtp.gmail.com"
         587 
         "MYEMAILADDRESS@gmail.com"
         "MY_NEW_APP_PASSWORD")))
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I have, hopefully it will help you. Works for sending via `C-x m` or the `gnus` interface, and I've had it set up for several months.

`~/.emacs`:

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(send-mail-function 'smtpmail-send-it)
 '(smtpmail-smtp-server "smtp.gmail.com")
 '(smtpmail-smtp-service 587))
```

`~/.authinfo`:

```
machine smtp.gmail.com login example@gmail.com password MY_APP_PASSWORD
```

Comment: Yes, that works.  I wish I knew why it works with the `.authinfo` file rather than entering the password directly in `smtp-auth-credentials`.  (Yes `.authinfo` is more secure when using gpg, but I'm mainly curious why inputting it directly failed.)  At any rate, thank you!